# Trace entire tree of nested object nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have a complex object that i need to extract the sublevels, i dont know how can i do it. I read abou recursive but i dont know how do it.

this is my object :

https://pastebin .com/m2dkiHkD

This object is from a table where the qLeft are dimensions that are printed in first column of table like this :

[Original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiu5H.png)

And my objective is do something like this :

[Objective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpjKA.png)

My idea is create an array with this new rows extracted from the complex object, so i can add in my new table

Thank you for any ideas

Comment: Your two images seem to be the same thing. Maybe you could try https://pastebin.com/ or just copy a subset of your raw data for us to look at, and maybe write a sample of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I fix the image and pastebin.

Comment: Could you also add some more background information, like where is this data coming from, is the Objective image obtained from just grabbing data from 1 file or multiple files, what do the different values mean?

Comment: This data came from an BI Tool (QlikSense), so i cant chenge this object, i just receive it.
The different values mean hierarchical dimensions like Argentina -> 1º -> MI and inside MI have 6 different products with values for each like price, and revenue, this stuff

Comment: I don't think adding one more level (to grab the products and prices) would be very different, it's just more loops on the lower level data to push into the main list. It's not as dynamic but I think that makes the code easier to read and maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a recursive data structure so recursion would not help, but what you need is to traverse the data and pick what the data you need like you said. The challenge is mostly in knowing which data you need and how to find it.

I think this might give you a start as to what you are trying to achieve,

```
// If there are multiple items inside qPivotDataPages you'll need to loop
// over those and call process for each one, then join the resulting arrays.
const data = json.qPivotDataPages[0].qLeft;

const result = process(data);

function process(input) {
    const [team1, team2] = input;
    const team1Results = processTeam(team1);
    const team2Results = processTeam(team2);
    return [...team1Results, ...team2Results];
}

function processTeam(teamData) {
    const teamResults = [];

    const teamName = teamData.qText;
    const halfDatas = teamData.qSubNodes.filter((item) => item.qText === '1ª' || item.qText === '2ª' || item.qText === 'InCia' );

    halfDatas.forEach((halfData) => {
        const half = halfData.qText;

        halfData.qSubNodes.forEach((item) => {
            if (item.qText === 'MI' || item.qText === 'ME') {
                teamResults.push({
                    team: teamName,
                    half: half,
                    type: item.qText,
                });
            }
        });
    });

    return teamResults;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think another challenge will be this dynamic. I think to use the length for qSubNodes but its a lot of loops

Comment: How does the data change when it's dynamic? I think the biggest challenge when transforming data is really understanding the data you're trying to transform. This data has very little "meta" information, all the variables are named similar things (qText) but mean different things at different levels, there's arrays but are they always in the same order, etc. If you can understand more about that I think it will be easier to make this code more flexible to handle more levels dynamically.